# ReportViewer control of devexpress in visual studio that does not recognize the LocalReport property

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, devexpress

My question is about the ReportViewer control of devexpress 12 in visual studio 2012 that does not recognize the LocalReport property, I am using Visual Studio 2012 and Devexpress.
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms, 
and it gives me error

```
        ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[2];
        parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("tipo_empresa", ASPxComboBox_Tipo_Empresa.Text);
        parameters[1] = new ReportParameter("empresa", ASPxComboBox_Empresa.Text);
       // RepViewerAccident.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
```

Error logs:

```
DevExpress.XtraReports.Web.ReportViewer 'does not contain a definition of' LocalReport 'nor was any extension method' LocalReport 'that accepts a first argument of type' DevExpress.XtraReports.Web.ReportViewer 'found (missing a usage directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Your error logs aren't understandable. Please post in English.

Comment: DevExpress.XtraReports.Web.ReportViewer 'does not contain a definition of' LocalReport 'nor was any extension method' LocalReport 'that accepts a first argument of type' DevExpress.XtraReports.Web.ReportViewer 'found (missing a usage directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go through [Use Report Parameters](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/4812/Detailed-Guide-to-DevExpress-Reporting/Shape-Report-Data/Use-Report-Parameters) documentation and you can [Request and Pass Report Parameter Values](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/10000/Detailed-Guide-to-DevExpress-Reporting/Shape-Report-Data/Use-Report-Parameters/Request-and-Pass-Report-Parameter-Values)

```
using DevExpress.XtraReports.Web;
//... 
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    XtraReport1 report = new XtraReport1();
    report.Parameters["parameter1"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["parameter1"]);
    ASPxWebDocumentViewer1.OpenReport(new CachedReportSourceWeb(report));
}
```

You can also create your custom report parameters - [Create Custom Report Parameters](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/9999/Detailed-Guide-to-DevExpress-Reporting/Shape-Report-Data/Use-Report-Parameters/Create-Custom-Report-Parameters)

```
using DevExpress.XtraReports.Parameters;
using DevExpress.XtraReports.UI;
// ... 

public enum Gender { Male, Female }

// Create a report instance. 
XtraReport report = new XtraReport();

// Create a new parameter. 
Parameter param = new Parameter();

// Specify required properties. 
param.Name = "GenderParameter";
param.Type = typeof(Gender);
param.Visible = true;

//Add the parameter to the report. 
report.Parameters.Add(param);
```